# Pass variable submitButton Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a way to send a variable for this method ?

```
<?= Html::submitButton('', ['class' => 'fa fa-file-excel-o btn btn-success btn-sm', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
```

Comment: can you make your question more clearer, please ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Excuse my English , but I want to send a variable for the button submin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this,

```
<?php echo Html::submitButton('Accept', ['name' => 'button1']) ?>

 if(isset($_POST['button1']))
    {
    // code here
    }
```

Comment: it didn't work for me... Help pls